# what went wrong with parseInt

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just encounter 1 problem on the parseInt
i do apply this parseInt for all my project but today i just encounter this

i have a normal text input `<input type='text' name='KG'>`
and i using jquery to retrieve the input value, then write into another input
`<input type='text' name='KG2'>`

below are my jquery code

```
$(":input[name='KG']").keyup(calc);
function calc(){
   var kg = $(":input[name='KG']").val();
   kg=parseInt(kg);
   $(":input[name='KG2']").val(kg);
}
```

guess what, this the result i get
input@KG   >   show@KG2
28   >   28
028   >   2
34   >   34
034   >   28
9   >   9
09   >   0

anyone know what went wrong? it can be solve by using Math.round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`028`, `034` and `09` are being treated as octal numbers because they start with `0` and you didn't specify a base. `8` and `9` are invalid digits, so you get `2` and `0` for the first and last, and the second one is converted to decimal `3*8 + 4 = 28`.

Use `parseInt(kg,10);`

Comment: For the record, that behaviour is obsolete in ES5 ([§ 15.1.2.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2)). Regardless, browsers that are otherwise compliant with ES5 still do the octal thing with leading zeros, so a radix will continue to be required for some time.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the second parameter which specifies which base to interpret the int in. To fix your example, try this:

```
$(":input[name='KG']").keyup(calc);
function calc(){
   var kg = $(":input[name='KG']").val();
   kg=parseInt(kg, 10);
   $(":input[name='KG2']").val(kg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to;

```
kg=parseInt(kg, 10);
```

You have to pass the radix (2nd argument) to `parseInt()` or it will guess based on the content.  The "guess" logic is all described [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseInt).

In your case, if the string starts with a `0` and not a `0x`, it will assume the string is octal which only respects 0-8 as legal characters and converts in base 8.

Moral of the story - ALWAYS pass the radix value to `parseInt()`.